# Can't find element to click on using Capybara + Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

**Background**: I'm using Capybara with Rspec to test a Rails 3 app.
**Driver used**: Selenium

**Problem**:
I can't find the "Sign in" button in order to click on from within my test.

**HTML code:**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="filter_form" id="login" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="clearfix login-fields">
              <label for="user_email">Email</label>
              <div class="input login-inputs">
                <input class="input-text" id="user_email" name="user[email]" placeholder="email" size="30" type="email" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix login-fields">
              <label for="user_password">Password</label>
              <div class="input login-inputs">
                <input class="input-text" id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="password" size="30" type="password">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="btn btn-primary login_btn" id="btn_login" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
            <a href="/lms/forgot_password" class="btn">Forgot password...</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn close cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Failing test**

```
it "should login correctly if the right credentials are given", :js => true do

    Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    visit '/'
    click_link('login_link') #this will bring a modal window with the code posted above using js
    within("#login") do
      fill_in 'user_email', :with => "my-email@example.com"
      fill_in 'user_password', :with => "mypwd"
    end

    response.should have_selector('input#btn_login') #This passes
    click_on("input#btn_login") #Here it fails, saying it can't find an element with that selector
    response.should have_selector(:xpath, '//div[@class="alert-message block-message info"]')
  end
```

My test file is inside `spec/requests`.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

Please try this:

```
page.find("#btn_login").click
```

Comment: It keeps complaining about not finding css even though # for an identifier is used.

Comment: It may be reason of you used same name for id twice

Answer (score 10):

This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348065/1504796

Is the right answer.

`click_on` does not take a CSS selector, but instead the text or id of a link. You want `click_on("btn_login")`. No hash sign or anything.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the first thing I tried, and got the same "not found" result.

Comment: jnicklas--thanks. I think Deleteman may also need to wait until the JS executes and the content is in the page. Is there a new syntax for wait_until? I'm on an older version at the moment. FYI Deleteman, jnicklas wrote Capybara. :-)

Answer (score 7):

try

```
find('#id',:visible => true).click
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding "gem 'launchy'" to your Gemfile and put 
"save_and_open_page" line before failed line in step file.

REFERENCE: http://techiferous.com/2010/04/using-capybara-in-rails-3/

Comment: Hey I did that, and the HTML saved has the button in there... but still, it won't find it.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to click on a submit button inside some modal css.  You'll need to invoke whatever displays that modal element first.

Comment: Check the test: ```click_link('login_link') #this will bring a modal window with the code posted above using js``` When I click on that link, that's what's supposed to be hapenning.

Comment: And you've confirmed that the modal element is visible afterward?  What happens if you alter the css so that it's never hidden?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think click_on will take a locator like that--I think it may want just an id, name or value. As an experiment, try replacing click_on("input#btn_login") with:

page.find('#btn_login').click

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck. When I try that I get the following error: "Unable to find css "#btn_login"" I also tried using XPath and no luck there.

Comment: Ok, a couple reality checks I'd try. Can you put response.should have_selector('#btn_login')  to be the line after visit '/'?  Just to rule out that that isn't already true before you click the link? Also, since ID's should be unique, you shouldn't need/use input in front of your id.

Comment: That test will return true, because the html for the modal is already on the site, only hidden. When you click the link, it'll get the html code, and move it someplace else inside the dom and show it.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. You'll need to instead do a wait_until{ find('#btn_login').visible? }  before the .click. Then let me know if the wait times out or not.

Comment: Try "synchronize" instead of wait_until.  It looks like that was renamed to synchronize in the recent release:  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/b100d1c29892a9e8a7c96a71192ef2b0aceea8ce

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but still no luck, I get the following error:  ```undefined method `synchronize' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x000000077a6f00>``` Ideas?

Comment: What version of capybara are you using? Could you take a look in the source/rubydoc to see what the synchronize method is named in that version? At one point there was resynchronize as well.

Answer (score 3):

- click_button("Sign in")
- find(:xpath, "//*[@id='btn_login']").click (or .trigger('click'))

If else fails, go through the console and see if you can check the presence of the button: document.getElementById("btn_login")

Comment: find(:xpath, "//*[@id='btn_login']").click  worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you know the link text, you can use `page.find_link(text).click`. ([source](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders:find_link))

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a save_and_open_page before the line in question. This should allow you to see the page and any errors that may prevent the clicking action.

Comment: Hey I did that, and the HTML saved has the button in there... but still, it won't find it

Answer (score 1):

I use capybara with chrome

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
                                                           :browser => :chrome) 
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

and install chrome driver:

```
brew install chromedriver
```

http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/09/27/use-chrome-with-cucumber-capybara/