# Capybara with :js => true causes tests to fail

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I started use Capybara a few days ago and I have never use Selenium before.
I want to see how my tests perform in beowser and use for it gem `selenium-webdriver`.
I have next test in Capybara:

```
RSpec.feature 'Authentication', :type => :feature do

    def register_with_form
      visit '/'
      click_on 'Account'
      click_on 'Register'
      fill_in 'Email', :with => 'test@example.com'
      fill_in 'Name', :with => 'John'
      fill_in 'Last name', :with => 'Smith'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => '1234567890'
      fill_in 'Password confirmation', :with => '1234567890'
      find('.testing-sign-up-class')
      click_button 'Sign up'
      expect(page).to have_css '.hd-title', 'Get Started'
    end

    scenario 'User registers' do
      register_with_form
      expect(page).to have_css '.hd-title', 'Get Started'
      expect(page).to have_css '.alert-success', 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
      expect(page).to have_css '.panel-title', 'What would you like to use GridHub for?'
    end

    scenario 'User sign out', :js => true do
      register_with_form
      click_on 'Account'
      click_on 'Logout'
      expect(page).to have_css '.alert-success', 'Signed out successfully.'
    end
end
```

Adding `:js => true` to any `scenario` broke test.
Console shows:

```
  1) Authentication When not registered User sign out
     Failure/Error: click_button 'Sign up'

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:


Element is not clickable at point (606, 23.73333740234375). Other element would receive the click: <input autocomplete="off" name="term" id="term" class="form-control nav-search-field main-ac autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="search items" data-url="/search" type="text">
```

I've added gem database_cleaner, my `spec_helper.rb` has next code:

```
  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

    if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

And my `bin/rspec` file has next line:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I assume that there is might be problem in browser of something else. Cause in some situations when test opens browser (I thied firefox and chrome), and some elements might be "below" browser's window, in such situation tests fails, cause can't find necessary button. 
If I have a time to scroll down browser's window, some of tests might be successful.

Comment: This might helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335303/cant-find-element-to-click-on-using-capybara-rails3

Answer (score 0):

When using any of the JS capable drivers `click_button` just clicks the button and then moves on.  It doesn't wait for anything on the page to change since it has no way of knowing what changes to expect.  My guess is that when your test calls register_with_form and returns, it immediately clicks the 'Account' link which is on the same page as the form.  That would end up cancelling the sign up submission and go to a page that has no Logout link.  To fix it you need to make the last line of register_with_form something like `expect(page).to have_content('Welcome!')` so it doesn't return until the signup has completed.

Additionally, use the recommended database_cleaner setup from https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example (the append_after being very important) rather than what you have, or you'll end up with hard to diagnose issues where your database starts to clean before requests have completed, etc.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't worked. I've update information in question.

Comment: @verrom you've done more than update the question, you've completely replaced the error that was there with a different one, making it a different question entirely